# Получить значение 2-ой ячейки таблицы

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Если обычная табличка в HTML:

```
<table><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr></table>
```

Известен номер строки. Как получить значение 2-ой ячейки?

Comment: А код таблицы вы не хотите показать? Или рассчитываете на телепатов?

Comment: Обычная табличка в HTML: <table><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr></table>

Comment: Код в сам вопрос вставьте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var index = $("#" + table + " tbody tr.info").index();
var secondTd = $("#" + table + " tbody tr").eq(index).find('td').eq(1).text();
```

Answer (score 2):

DOM объект таблицы имеет свойство rows, это Array-like объект содержащий все строки, который в свою очередь содержит Array-like объект cells, содержащий все столбцы.

Пример использования: http://jsfiddle.net/2jhueotn/

```
document.getElementById('table').rows[1].cells[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var numRow = 1,
    numCell = 1;

var row = $("table tr").eq(numRow);
var cell = $("td", row).eq(numCell);

console.log(cell.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>*</td><td>0</td><td>#</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью jquery:

```
 var row = 1;
   var data = $('table tr:nth-child(' + row + ')').find('td:nth-child(2)').html();
   console.log(data);
```